# Configurable product quick add to cart

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, magento2.1.6

I'm looking for a way to add configurable product to cart from catalog page. When i look demo theme site they all have customisation of product in catalog, itis a module ?

I find many solution on google but no one worked.

Also there is a way to set default configuration for product (the checkbox default in attribute don't work) i try with js but the image and price aren't updated.

Comment: Default LUMA theme provide this option. You no need to look for other.

Comment: Where it is in the LUMA Theme ? i use it and didn't see it

Comment: Go to admin and activate LUMA theme: ADMIN->CONTENT>Configuration. Click on edit link. Look for " Applied Theme" under default theme tab. Select 'Magento Luma' from drop-down.

Comment: And no it don't show n catalog, i use Luma, i change it in content configuration and nothing change..

Comment: Do you have Configurable-products or sample-data install? This is link of LUMA DEFAULT with sample-data: http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/women/tops-women/hoodies-and-sweatshirts-women.html

Comment: hmmm i don't get what are sample data. I have configurable product with some configuration (choolate or cofee for exemple) and i want it to be display like your link in catalog

Comment: please install magento with sample-data and you will have solution for your problem. You are on initial stage so you should start with installing sample-data.

Comment: hmmm ok so how i do this ?

Comment: Install new magento with sample data

Comment: wow i really need to re install it i just can't upgrade current megento ?

Comment: Sure you can and install new only if you didnt do much custom work. Better you can install only sample-data , thats what only you needed

Comment: yeah i find http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/sample-data-before-composer.html

Comment: hmm so i run sampledata:deploy and setup:upgrade and nothing changed ... magento 2.1.6
Edit : I have magento LUMA everywhere :)
Edit 2 : The homepage changeand i see same as the link you give

Comment: Edit 3 : wow that change all the default websites with category of demo. But no product.

Comment: clear and flush cache. reindex.  And check products are available in admin?

Comment: cache clean cache flush index reindex cache clean and same. In product page my product have the configuration choice, with swatch text like the tee-shirt size of demo, but in catalog there isn't the possibility to select attribute and add to cart

Answer (score 0):

For quick view, you can try the following extension and try if this works or not for you.

https://www.weltpixel.com/advance-product-quick-view.html

However, this extension is domain specific. For changing the image and price dynamically, you need to do changes in js file.

Comment: Thanks but it's not what i want, i don't want my customers have to open the pop up and select it, they need to do it from catalog view

Comment: @Nundra can you please give me the link for demo site so that I can help you more with this thing ?

Comment: sure, this one : http://newsmartwave.net/magento2/porto/demo2_en/fashion/women/tops-blouses.html and many other demo site